# How to use delimiter using scanner when the file contain "0195153448";"Classical Mythology";"Mark P. O. Morford";"2002";"Oxford University Press"

Tags: java

How to use delimiter using scanner in java when the Text file contain the following line.

```
"0195153448";"Classical Mythology";"Mark P. O. Morford";"2002";"Oxford University Press"
```

How to get the output:

```
0195153448
Classical Mythology
Mark P. O. Morford
2002
Oxford University Press
```

Please tell me how to use scanner delimiter in java here.

Comment: Why not read in the whole line and use `split` method?

Answer (score 0):

scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(";")); 
scanner.useDelimiter("");